# mysqld limit memory useage of process

Tags: memory, junit, server, mariadb, mariadb4j

I am using mariadb4j for junit tests. This runs a mysql process in memory.
Now when I spawn the process it basically takes all available memory from the system, which is problematic for other processes.

Is there a way to limit the memory allocated to the mysqld process on startup via command line arguments?
Or in a different way that I cannot think of right now?

Thanks

**Edit** As correctly pointed out, Mariadb is launched instead of mysql, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Mariadb4j launches mariadb, not mysql instance. No, the two are not the same, just very similar, but increasingly different.